# exit handler for express to close all open connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I have a node-express app and via node child process i run a binary and make requests that would bring back streaming data which is send to the browser via SSE in stdout.on('data') handler. I have a child.on('exit') handler and whenever the binary goes down the exit handler gets invoked and i could see the appropriate exitCode, in addition to that i would like to close all the open connections and make express server not to accept any new requests and gracefully close it out.

Is there a way to grab all the open connections and close them out in the exit handler.

Answer (score 0):

`app.listen` returns a wrapped HTTP server, on which you can call `.close()`, which will gracefully close open connections and stop allowing incoming connections.

Something like:

```
let server = app.listen(9000)
child.on("exit", () => server.close())
```